# Adding initial line on right side of document for each line

Tags: formatting, lists, rules

I'm creating a series of standard operating procedures in LaTeX that requires an initial next to each list item to say it's complete. Is there any way to automatically add a right aligned initial line off to the right side of the text or in a second column for each item?

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
 Please initial each line item of the procedure.
\begin{itemize}
   \item First item needing an initial line next to it..
   \item Second item needing an initial line next to it.
   \item Another lines with initial.
\end{itemize}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Some text
  \item Some more text
  \item blah, blah.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The line is in the margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[heightadjust]{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}    
\let\Item\item
\renewcommand\item{\marginnote{\hrulefill}[1.6\baselineskip]\Item}
\begin{document}        
    Please initial each line item of the procedure.

    \begin{itemize}
        \item First item needing an initial line next to it.
        \item \sloppy\lipsum[2]
        \item Another lines with initial.
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Some text
        \item Some more text
        \item blah, blah.
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following provides `initialitemize` that inserts a regular `\item` plus an underline (of `3em`, on the baseline) in the right margin (on the first line of each `\item`). The space between the initial and the margin is `~`, but that can be changed as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{initialitemize}
  {\begin{itemize}
    \let\olditem\item
    \renewcommand{\item}{%
      \olditem\leavevmode
      \makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\makebox[0pt][l]{~\rule{3em}{.4pt}}}}%
      \ignorespaces}}
  {\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

Please initial each line item of the procedure.

\begin{initialitemize}
  \item First item needing an initial line next to it.
  \item \sloppy\lipsum[2]
  \item Another lines with initial.
\end{initialitemize}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Some text
  \item Some more text
  \item blah, blah.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

A copy can be made for an `enumerate` version.